# How can I render a bar code as an image through google app engine with python?

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine

After a day's reading, I'm no closer to finding a good way to render a bar code through Google app engine on python. The closest I've found is PyPNG as a pure python image library but it looks as though that would require quite a bit of work to make it usable. Does anyone have any good suggestions on how to do it before i walk down the tumultuous path of rolling my own?

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: I found at least three by doing a Google search for Python Bar Code.  What's wrong with those solutions?  All of them seem pretty good to me.  What requirements do you have that invalidate all the ones that turn up on Google?

Comment: Have a look at the google charts api. You can use it to generate many types of barcode based on url parameters.

Comment: @S.Lott Dan is right - anything that depends on PIL or Cairo for it's image generation tool won't work on Google's App Engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at a webservice to generate the barcode. I found the site below on google but there are many results if you search for: barcode webservice. Many of them are code for you to download and use but some appear to be live webservices.

http://www.barcodesoft.com/barcode-generator-webservice.aspx

Edit: Now that I think about it another option may be to generate the barcode in js/html depending on your need. This SO question/answers might be helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835082/what-is-the-best-javascript-barcode-generator

Comment: thanks for your answer - it  looks like I  might have to settle for one of those options. I'd thought of the javascript option http://zanstra.com/my/BarcodeClock.html but didn't want to have to worry about browser inconsistencies. I'd also assume the caching works better with an image.